# Disable tabindex nav on iOS

Tags: javascript, html, ios, tabindex

I'm trying to disable prev/next buttons for tabindex nav on iOS. I have two fields in my HTML:

```
<form>
...
<select></select>
...
<input />
...
</form>
```

The goal is to have these prev/next buttons disabled when focusing on any of these two fields:

[image]

I already tried the following:

- setting 0 tabindex for both fields
- setting negative tabindex for both fields
- setting big tabindex for one field (e.g. 1000) and small for another (1); same for negative
- dynamic tabindex switch on focus
- dynamic disabling the next/prev field on focus
- using <div> instead on a <form>
- having one field outside of a <form>

Any ideas how it can be done?

Comment: Is it possible to assign their visibility as hidden?

Comment: did you ever find a solution?